# How do I use Entity Framework 4.1 with MVC 3 Login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I am building my first EF 4.1 code first application in mvc3. How do I incorporate the mvc3 login with my EF4.1 classes?

or maybe the question should be, how do I build the same login functionality into my EF4.1 classes?

My EF classes will contain user information, which is what I want to use for the login.

any suggestions are appretiated.

Comment: What is the "MVC 3 Login"? Do you mean the AccountController functionality which the standard MVC3 project template creates?

Comment: Can you describe a bit more in detail what you want to achieve? (You can edit your question and put more info in there.) Otherwise I am afraid you don't get a really helpful answer. The standard AccountController uses the ASP.NET MembershipProvider and manages the DB tables behind (Users, Roles, Profiles, etc.) in a more old-fashioned way (stored procedures mainly). You don't need EF classes for that. Do you want to throw this away and write your own membership system (including all security concerns) using EF? Or what is your goal?

Answer (score 2):

Please see [asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc) for a bunch of great tutorials about ASP.NET MVC. Also [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs) is a good link on user authentication.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand from your question, you will need to implement Custom Membership Provider and override all the properties you need...refer to this article fro complete information..

http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2009/10/14/Implementing-custom-Membership-Provider-and-Role-Provider-for-Authinticating-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx